Fix for warning "Failed to generate cache key for https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[api-key]"?
I'm using the alchemy-sdk with Next.js 14, and I get a warning message "Failed to generate cache key for https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[api-key]". The api-key is a simple alchemy api key in an environment variable. I cannot find anything related to this warning or how to solve it. If anyone knows anything about how to fix this, please share!
